# swi prolog- IDE - Eclipse- how to use it in Linux?

Tags: swi-prolog

I read that Swi Prolog IDE - Eclipse - in Linux(Ubuntu) is possible. However I couldn't get the installed Eclipse to 'use' swi Prolog.
Please help

Comment: Could you be more specific? Both SWI and Eclipse work, separately, on my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog Development Tools (ProDT) is a Prolog Integrated Development Environment (IDE) aiming to be as rich in functionality as the Eclipse's java IDE, giving the developer a single environment where it can control the development of a Prolog project from code edition, test execution, etc...

This project stands on top of Eclipse's projects to take advantage of its already existent features and its extensibility and works on any environment Eclipse works including windows, linux and mac OSX.

It support as underlying interpreters: SWI-prolog, XSB prolog, B-prolog

The site has more information about the project including installation and features list: http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/

Hope you can find it useful!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that Amzi! works for linux environments, you can try this http://www.amzi.com/download/prolog_download_sites.htm but i'm not sure if it has the desired results. good luck!

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.  
How to use Swi in Ubuntu directly? I download using the Ubuntu Software Centre but can't see it available

Answer (score -1):

In case someone just wanted to compile a program using swi in ubuntu.
use termainal using the command:

```
$swip <file name>
```